# List databases in SQL Server and skipping master

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have the following query to list all the databases in SQL Server:

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases ;
```

That works fine, but what I'm trying to skip the following databases from the results:

```
master, tempdb, model, msdb
```

I know I have to use the `CASE` statement somehow, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: `where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')`?

Comment: @DaleK that was painfully obvious, I'm not sure why i was trying to overcomplicate the solution.

Comment: we've all been there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with a `where` clause:

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
```